# lua - garry's mod - attempt to call global 'Player' (a table value)

Tags: lua, garrys-mod

When trying start Garry's Mod server i get an error:

> [ERROR]
> gamemodes/darkrp/gamemode/modules/base/sv_gamemode_functions.lua:227:
> attempt to call global 'Player' (a table value)
>
> 1. unknown - gamemodes/darkrp/gamemode/modules/base/sv_gamemode_functions.lua:227

sv_gamemode_functions.lua:217-230

> function GM:EntityRemoved(ent)
>
> ```
> self.Sandbox.EntityRemoved(self, ent)
> if ent:IsVehicle() then
>     local found = ent:CPPIGetOwner()
>     if IsValid(found) then
>         found.Vehicles = found.Vehicles or 1
>         found.Vehicles = found.Vehicles - 1
>     end
> end
> local owner = ent.Getowning_ent and ent:Getowning_ent() or Player(ent.SID or 0)
> if ent.DarkRPItem and IsValid(owner) then owner:removeCustomEntity(ent.DarkRPItem) end
> if ent.isKeysOwnable and ent:isKeysOwnable() then ent:removeDoorData() end end
> ```

please help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

change this line

```
local owner = ent.Getowning_ent and ent:Getowning_ent() or Player(ent.SID or 0)
```

to

```
local owner = ent :GetOwner()
```

https://wiki.facepunch.com/gmod/Entity:GetOwner
https://wiki.facepunch.com/gmod/Player:UserID

Answer (score -1):

The problem is not in this part of code.
Something overrode `Player` global variable with a table.

You need to find why this happened.

If after the fix Player won't work, try `Entity(ent.SID or 0)`, maybe it's a EntityIndex not UserID.

Entity:GetOwner (as Doyousketch2 suggested) won't help you because it's used for parenting not ownability.

Comment: You're thinking of `ent:getParent()`  https://wiki.facepunch.com/gmod/Entity:GetParent

Comment: @Doyousketch2
> This function is generally used to disable physics interactions on projectiles being fired by their owner, but can also be used for normal ownership in case physics interactions are not involved at all. The Gravity gun will be able to pick up the entity even if the owner can't collide with it, the Physics gun however will not.
https://wiki.facepunch.com/gmod/Entity:SetOwner

Comment: You're pointing out a function that isn't being used in this script.  What's the relevance here?

Comment: @Doyousketch2 But your answer mentions this functions as right decision, we don't use this function for ownership

Comment: I have already fixed this error, @Doyousketch2's answer is correct

Comment: @lksmnd If that fixed your problem that means someone's used SetOwner for ownership, I won't be impressed if your gamemode is doing this.